# Override Woocommerce public function

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to override this function from `class-product-addon-cart.php` to my child theme `functions.php`:

```
/**
     * add_cart_item function.
     *
     * @access public
     * @param mixed $cart_item
     * @return void
     */
    public function add_cart_item( $cart_item ) {
        // Adjust price if addons are set
        if ( ! empty( $cart_item['addons'] ) && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_addons_adjust_price', true, $cart_item ) ) {

            $extra_cost = 0;

            foreach ( $cart_item['addons'] as $addon ) {
                if ( $addon['price'] > 0 ) {
                    $extra_cost += $addon['price'];
                }
            }

            $cart_item['data']->adjust_price( $extra_cost );
        }

        return $cart_item;
    }
```

**I have a type of products called accomodation product from Woocommerce booking plugin** Here's the code from booking class :

```
/**
 * Class for the booking product type
 */
class WC_Product_Booking extends WC_Product {
    private $availability_rules = array();

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct( $product ) {
        if ( empty ( $this->product_type ) ) {
            $this->product_type = 'booking';
        }

        parent::__construct( $product );
    }
```

So if this product is an accomodation product then execute the function.

I wrote this code but it does not work :

```
$accomodation = new WC_Product_Booking( get_the_ID() );
$product = new WC_Product( get_the_ID() );

if ($accomodation) {
    add_filter('woocommerce_product_addons_adjust_price', '__return_false');
} elseif($product) {
    add_filter('woocommerce_product_addons_adjust_price', true);
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: try `add_filter('woocommerce_product_addons_adjust_price', '__return_false');`

Comment: It works, now I don't know if you can help from there, but do you know how to say if this product is a simple product or variable then add this line of code ?

Comment: please check my answer and let me know if it works..

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_addons_adjust_price', 'rei_product_addons_adjust_price', 10, 2);    
function rei_product_addons_adjust_price($is_adjust,$cart_item ){
    $product = $cart_item['data'];

    if ($product->is_type('booking')) {
        $is_adjust = false;
    }

    return $is_adjust;

}
```

Comment: I have updated the code.. try it... this would remove `foreach` if type is booking... if that's what you mean...

Comment: I believe this is now not related to the last question... it's not the same file to be edited.. this time you could have accepted the answer if that work for the last question and asked another one.