# If simple product Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In my child theme `functions.php` file, I want to add a condition where if the product is a simple product then run this function or not.

So I wrote this code :

```
if($product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) {
    add_filter('woocommerce_product_addons_adjust_price', '__return_false');
}
```

But it does not work.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: no need to repost.. you can edit your original question for additional info.. -- duplicate of [Override Woocommerce public function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35056484/override-woocommerce-public-function)

Comment: check https://wordpress.org/support/topic/condition-to-check-if-product-is-simple-or-variable